# <link rel=preload> with additonal HTTP headers

Tags: html, http, browser, authorization, preload

I added a preload for my site like this `<link rel=preload href=http://api.github.com/... as=fetch crossorigin=anonymous>` which is `fetch()`ed later. It worked very well (the preload request sent to the remote server at the very beginning of loading, and answer came back, everything was fine).

Later I added an `Authorization: Bearer ...` to the `fetch()` call (because of other reasons), which is caused that the preload's HTTP headers do not match the later fetch's HTTP headers, so the entire preload result is not re-used anymore (Both Chrome and Firefox are correctly notify me about this).

I also tried to add the preload with `Link` HTTP header to the main page's response, but that did not help as well.

So the current sitation is this: I can't add the same `Authorization` header to preload request because it is simply not possible, so the two request are never will be the same, so the preload is useless anymore.

Please correct me and advise:

- Is there a way to add that `Authorization: Bearer ...` to the preload request to?
- OR is there a way to ask the browser to ignore that difference between to two request's headers?
- OR any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web standards do not allow for such a possibility.

The Fetch standard [defines](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-fetch) the conditions under which prefetched resources may be used as follows:

> To **fetch**, given a [request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request) *request*, […] run the steps below. […]
>
> 11. If all of the following conditions are true:
>
>     - […]
>     - *request*’s [unsafe-request flag](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#unsafe-request-flag) is not set or *request*’s [header list](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-header-list) [is empty](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#list-is-empty)
>
>     then:
>
>     3. Let *foundPreloadedResource* be the result of invoking [consume a preloaded resource](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#consume-a-preloaded-resource) for [*request*]

Having an `Authorization` header in the `fetch` request disqualifies it from reusing preloaded resources.  Unless you happen to know of a non-standard extension that allows you to bypass this, this means there is no way to prefetch a resource with custom headers.

There are three ways you can resolve this: skip the `Authorization` header in the request proper, give up on preloading entirely, or reimplement prefetching yourself.  That is, inject a script that fetches the resource early during page loading, preferably gated by [`network.connection && !network.connection.saveData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/saveData), and stores it in your own cache, then simply look up the data there.

The order I listed those solutions is one of, in my opinion, decreasing appropriateness.  Prefetching has been designed mostly for the sake of static resources that present the same to any user that may want to download them; as such, an `Authorization` header is not supposed to matter, so if you can get away with avoiding it, do.  If authorization does matter, then maybe the resource isn’t such a great candidate for prefetching.  If you insist though, you can do it manually.

Comment: Hi really good answer! Thank you very much!
The authorization matters because the server applies rate limiting without it. So I can decide between rate limiting for my users and having short response time... good